# Android OkHttpClient - download file with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I edit the question with the code I have so far now after helping from answers:

```
                val folder = File(context.cacheDir, "videos")

                val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(fileUrl).build()
                OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                        // Method body omitted for brevity
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
                        if (!folder.exists()) {
                            val folderCreated: Boolean = folder.mkdir()
                        }
                        val file = File(folder.path.toString() + "/video.mp4")
                        
                        
                        val fileCreated: Boolean = file.createNewFile()
                        val sink: BufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file))
                        sink.writeAll(response.body().source())
                        sink.close()
                    }
                })
```

I get

```
Using 'buffer(Sink): BufferedSink' is an error. moved to extension function
```

on

`buffer` in `Okio.buffer`

```
Using 'sink(File): Sink' is an error. moved to extension function
```

on

`sink` in `Okio.sink`

and

```
Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val
```

on

```
`body` in `response.body()`
```

Comment: See [this](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/download-file-in-android-with-kotlin-874d50bccaa2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. The first is that you need to remove the parentheses from your object expression, since Callback is an interface:

```kotlin
OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
```

The second is that your method signatures are wrong. The parameters of `onFailure` and `onSuccess` are not nullable (so you can't use `?`), and `Response` has no generic type:

```kotlin
override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
  // Method body omitted for brevity
}

override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
  // Method body omitted for brevity
}
```

As for your error with `sink`, the version of OkHttp I'm using (`4.9.1`) has this method deprecated. The following logic with extension functions works for me:

```kotlin
val sink: BufferedSink = file.sink().buffer()
```

I also got a deprecation error on your call to `sink.writeAll(response.body().source())`, which I replaced with the following:

```kotlin
val body = response.body
                    
if (body != null) {
  val sink: BufferedSink = file.sink().buffer()
  sink.writeAll(body.source())
  sink.close()
}
```

However it might be better to do this check earlier to avoid creating a bunch of empty files.

Comment: I get: One type argument expected for class Response<T : Any!>

Comment: Then you might be using a different version of OkHttp. The above example is valid for both 4.5.0 and 4.9.1.

Comment: After downgrading to 4.5.0 I still get this error

Comment: Perhaps you're importing the wrong `Response`?

Comment: yeah after removing all imports from okhttp the Response is still there with the error, looks like it uses Response from volley, but I can't remove volley since I'm using it for other stuff, what to do?

Comment: You can use the fully qualified classname: `override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {`

Comment: I clicked "let us discuss in chat" by accident sorry, I updated the question

Comment: I've edited my answer to also address your issues with `sink` and `response.body`

Comment: ALL WORKS! Also sharing, the suffering is over I'll upload the app and won't touch this awful software called android for months, THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the code a bit

```
val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(fileUrl).build()
OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            val folderCreated: Boolean = folder.mkdir()
        }
        val file = File(folder.getPath().toString() + "/video.mp4")
        if (file.exists()) {
            val fileDeleted: Boolean = file.delete()

        }
        val fileCreated: Boolean = file.createNewFile()
        val sink: BufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file))
        sink.writeAll(response.body().source())
        sink.close()
    }
})
```

Comment: I get 'onFailure' hides member of supertype 'Callback' and needs 'override' modifier and 'onResponse' hides member of supertype 'Callback' and needs 'override' modifier. After adding override I get: One type argument expected for class Response<T : Any!>